# Incomplete warning message after upgrading from 16.04 to 18.04, then from 18.04 to 20.04, related to Hardware Enablement Stack (HWE)

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, upgrade, 20.04

This is a VM in VirtualBox.

I have the feeling that the following message is trying to tell me something, but is unable to tell me what exactly is going on

This appears since the upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04, so it got carried over to 20.04

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-28-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

  System information as of Fri 01 May 2020 12:11:08 PM CEST

  System load:  1.75                Processes:                312
  Usage of /:   28.6% of 117.25GB   Users logged in:          0
  Memory usage: 25%                 IPv4 address for docker0: 172.17.0.1
  Swap usage:   0%                  IPv4 address for eth0:    xxxxxxxxxxxxxx

  => There is 1 zombie process.


0 updates can be installed immediately.
0 of these updates are security updates.


You have packages from the Hardware Enablement Stack (HWE) installed that
are going out of support on 2025-04-30.

To upgrade to a supported (or longer-supported) configuration:

* Upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04 LTS to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS by running:
sudo do-release-upgrade -p

OR

* Switch to the current security-supported stack by running:
sudo apt-get install

and reboot your system.
```

Shouldn't the line `sudo apt-get install` contain the package name?

Doing an `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` does not help.

Doing an `apt-get install` did also not help:

```
$ sudo apt-get install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libaec-dev libaec0 libeccodes-data libgfortran4 libgl1-mesa-glx libsz2 linux-image-4.4.0-178-generic linux-modules-4.4.0-178-generic
  linux-modules-extra-4.4.0-178-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

$ sudo apt autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libaec-dev libaec0 libeccodes-data libgfortran4 libgl1-mesa-glx libsz2 linux-image-4.4.0-178-generic linux-modules-4.4.0-178-generic
  linux-modules-extra-4.4.0-178-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 9 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 271 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 142621 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing libaec-dev:amd64 (1.0.4-1) ...
Removing libsz2:amd64 (1.0.4-1) ...
Removing libaec0:amd64 (1.0.4-1) ...
Removing libeccodes-data (2.16.0-1) ...
Removing libgfortran4:amd64 (7.5.0-6ubuntu2) ...
Removing libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 (20.0.4-2ubuntu1) ...
Removing linux-modules-extra-4.4.0-178-generic (4.4.0-178.208) ...
Removing linux-image-4.4.0-178-generic (4.4.0-178.208) ...
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-178-generic
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-28-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-28-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-99-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-99-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-34-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-34-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
done
Removing linux-modules-4.4.0-178-generic (4.4.0-178.208) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9) ...
```

The end of the upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04 printed out

```
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.64ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: warning: package not in status nor available database at line 2: gcc-5:amd64
dpkg: warning: package not in status nor available database at line 3: libharfbuzz-dev:amd64
dpkg: warning: package not in status nor available database at line 4: libharfbuzz-icu0:amd64
dpkg: warning: package not in status nor available database at line 5: libisl19:amd64
dpkg: warning: found unknown packages; this might mean the available database is outdated, and needs to be updated through a frontend method; please see the FAQ <https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/Dpkg/FAQ>

System upgrade is complete.
```

How can I find the root of this problematic message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to find the root cause of this message, it turns out that an obsolete Linux kernel was still installed.

What I did was first find the source of this message, `/etc/update-motd.d/95-hwe-eol` printed it out.

This file actually just executed the file `/usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-hwe-eol`.

Among other stuff, that file executed `/usr/bin/hwe-support-status`, which is a Python script which actually generates the message after doing some checking.

Among the things this file checks is a regex for kernel images:

```
UNSUPPORTED_KERNEL_IMAGE_REGEX = \
    r'linux-image.*-(3\.16|3\.19|4\.2)(\.[0-9]+)?-.*'
```

My `/boot/` directory contained the following files:

```
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4.0K May  1 12:12 .
drwxr-xr-x 22 root root 4.0K May  1 11:59 ..
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4.0K May  1 12:12 grub
-rw-------  1 root root 3.6M Mar 11  2016 System.map-4.2.0-34-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 3.9M Apr 22 20:31 System.map-4.15.0-99-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 4.6M Apr 22 16:08 System.map-5.4.0-28-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1.3M Mar 11  2016 abi-4.2.0-34-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 181K Mar 11  2016 config-4.2.0-34-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 213K Apr 22 20:31 config-4.15.0-99-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 233K Apr 22 16:08 config-5.4.0-28-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  31M May  1 11:59 initrd.img-4.2.0-34-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  40M May  1 11:58 initrd.img-4.15.0-99-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  48M May  1 12:06 initrd.img-5.4.0-28-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 179K Feb 14 00:09 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 181K Feb 14 00:09 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 181K Feb 14 00:09 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw-------  1 root root 6.5M Mar 11  2016 vmlinuz-4.2.0-34-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 8.0M Apr 22 20:32 vmlinuz-4.15.0-99-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  12M Apr 22 16:43 vmlinuz-5.4.0-28-generic
```

which hinted that the unsupported `4.2.0` kernel was installed.

In order to find what exactly made the script print out that message, I made a copy of that script and modified it to print out the problematic packages.

```
21:15 user@machine [dev] ~/debug-hwe$ ./hwe-support-status --show-all-unsupported --verbose --show-replacements
show_all_unsupported True
unsupported backport linux-image-4.2.0-34-generic
unsupported backport linux-image-extra-4.2.0-34-generic
```

So doing a `sudo apt purge linux-image-4.2.0-34-generic` removed both these packages which resulted in the message disappearing.

Basically it was nothing harmful, as that kernel was no longer used, but good to clean it up anyway. I also removed `4.15.0` since I also didn't need that.

It appears that the script is a bit buggy in what refers to printing out messages related to kernel-related issues.

Comment: Having the same issue after upgrading from 18 to 20. Some good info here, except on mine the command `./hwe-support-status --show-all-unsupported --verbose --show-replacements` shows nothing. And pretty sure it's not my kernel as all I have is two 5.3.0 kernels installed. "do-release-upgrade" and "sudo apt install" also do nothing. I see no issues on system other than this annoyance. Any other advice on tracking down what's causing it?

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem after upgrading from 16.04 to 20.04.

The `./hwe-support-status --show-all-unsupported --verbose` shows nothing but `ubuntu-security-status --unavailable` (since update-manager 1:20.04.9 version of April 2020, before it was `ubuntu-support-status`) reveal some packages from previous major update, `linux-headers-generic-lts-utopic` triggered the motd warning in my case.

Seem I've some cleanup to do ;)